# PHP 2d Array Declaration

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am trying to define a 2d array in php. I have some concept code so you can see the situation:

```
    class Testing { 
        protected $requiredFieldsByReferenceType = array(
           ['Book']['volume'] => true,
           ['Book']['source'] => true,
           ['Book Section']['volume'] => true,
           ['Book Section']['source'] => true,
           ['Chart or Table']['volume'] => true,
           ['Chart or Table']['source'] => true
        );
        print_r($requiredFieldsByReferenceType);
     }//End Testing
```

The error that is thrown:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   '[', expecting ')'

Comment: I kept reading the title as "deceleration".  I think the misplaced E (it's "declAration") threw me off.

Comment: @Frank , I edited the question's answer to be correct :)

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are good.
The syntax using array() is:

```
$requiredFieldsByReferenceType = array('Book'=>array('volume' => true,
                                                     'source' => true),
                                       'Book Section'=>array('volume' => true,
                                                             'source' => true)
                                       );
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use [`array()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) inside the array value declarations too:

```
protected $myArray = array(
    "Book" => array(
        "item1" => true,
        "item2" => true
    ),
    "Chest" => array(
        "item1" => true,
        "item2" => false
    )
);
```

Comment: How would I access it then? The normal way?

$myArray['Book']['item1'] = false?

Comment: @Diego: Yes. After you’ve build that array, you can access it via the `$variable[…]` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
$requiredFieldsByReferenceType ['Book']['volume'] = true;
$requiredFieldsByReferenceType ['Book']['source'] = true;
$requiredFieldsByReferenceType ['Book Section']['volume'] = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Only the answers that assign the array in ONE statement are going to work in your context (defining a class property) unless you put them all in the constructor.  By the same token, I don't think that print_r is going to work without being in a method...

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr1 = array(
    array(value1,value2,value3),
    array(value4,value5,value6),
    array(value7,value8,value9),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is by nesting array() functions:

```
 $requiredFieldsByReferenceType = array(
           'Book' => array('volume' => true,
                                       'source' => true),
           'Book Section' => array('volume' => true,
                                                     'source' => true),
         ...
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't do multi-dimensional arrays. You must construct it as arrays of arrays.

```
protected $myArray = array(
  'Book' => array(
    'item1' => true,
    'item2' => true,
  ),
  'Chest' => array(
  ),
    'item1' => true,
    'item2' => false,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Class TestClass {
    protected $myArray = array(
        "Book" => array('item1' => true, 'item2' => false),
        "chest" => array('item1' => true, 'item2' => false),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to define an array is `array(key0 => value0,  key1 => value1, key2 => value2, ...)`. Since a two-dimensional array in PHP is just multiple arrays as values in an array, it would look like this:

```
$myArray =
    array(
        'Book' =>
            array(
                'item1' => true,
                'item2' => true
            ),
        'Chest' =>
            array(
                'item1' => true,
                'item2' => false
            )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
    $myArray = array(
            'book' => array(
                'item1' => true,
                'item2' => true
            ),
            'chest' => array(
                'item1' => true,
                'item2' => true,
            )
        );
```

By the way you shouldn't initialize your attribues like this.
Rather use getters/setters.

```
class TestClass {
    protected $_myArray;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setMyArray();
    }

    public function setMyArray()
    {
        $this->_myArray = array(
            'book' => array(
                'item1' => true,
                'item2' => true
            ),
            'chest' => array(
                'item1' => true,
                'item2' => true,
            )
        );
    }
}


$foo = new TestClass();
print_r($foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing styles of appending to an array here.

try

```
$arr = array(
    'key' => array ('key2' => 'value 1', 'key3' => 'value2'),
    'key12' => array('key4' => 'value4')
);
```

or

```
$arr = array();

$arr['key1'] = array();
$arr['key2'] = array();

$arr['key1']['key3'] = 'value1';
```

(Please note my examples don't produce the same data structure, I was just demonstrating the different methods)